# Splitting multiple files together

Tags: perl, bash, shell, unix, awk

I have 70 files that looks like (file1 = complex.1.txt;... file69 = complex.69.txt... file70 = complex.70.txt)

```
ATOM   7066  O   GLY A 784      49.130  43.743 -23.586  1.00  1.00           O  
nnn
CONECT  337  403 
END
ATOM      1  N   ARG B   1      26.564 -17.621   9.457  1.00  1.00           N1+
ATOM      2  CA  ARG B   1      26.733 -18.764   8.526  1.00  1.00           C
```

I want to break all 70 files in two parts. The second file will start after END. The splitted file name will be complex.1.txt_part1 and complex.1.txt_part2 and so on for all files.
I tried the awk solution

```
for ((i=1;i<=70;i++)); do awk '{file="complex.1.txt_part"++k;printf "%s%s",$0,RS > file;close(file)}' RS='END\n' complex.$i.txt; done
```

but it gives only 2 files in result. Could someone correct this or post the other nice solutions.

Answer (score 4):

gawk has `FILENAME` built-in variable, which could be useful for your requirement. This one-liner should do the job:

```
awk 'FNR==1{f=0}{print > FILENAME (f?"_part2":"_part1")}/END/{f=1}' complext.*.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Perl one-liner solution:

```
perl -n0e '$k=1; for (split /(?<=^END\n)/m) { open $fh, ">complex.$..txt_part".$k++; print $fh $_ }' complex.*.txt
```

### Explanation

It uses these two special command line-options:

`-n`

...tells Perl to read the given input files record-by-record, and run the specified one-liner for each record. By default a record is one line, but...

`-0`

...tells Perl to treat the "null byte" rather than "newline" as the input record separator, so a whole file will count as one record.

Then in the one-liner code itself:

- `split /(?<=^END\n)/m`

  ...splits the input record into two strings, using a [look-behind assertion](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#%28?%3C=pattern%29-%5CK) which matches the string END at the beginning of a line and followed by a newline.
- `for (...) { ... }`

  ...makes sure that the right part is done separately for each of the two split strings
- `open $fh, ">..."; print $fh $_`

  ...opens a new file for writing, and then writes the current split string to it
- `$.`

  ...special variable that refers to the current input record number (i.e. it is automatically incremented by one for each record that is read).
- `$k=1; ... $k++`

  ...this is so the output file will end with "_part1" on the the first iteration of the `for` loop, but "_part2" on the second iteration, for each input record.

Comment: Hm, so it seems that while stackoverflow _allows_ `dl`/`dd`/`dt` tags, it does not provide an appropriate style for them? Too bad...